# Need to post JSON object from Android

Tags: android, json

I need to  send a json object containing a mix of `string`, `integer` and `double` data to a MongoDB.

The problem is I'm unable to send the object from my Activity to the Service which I'm using to connect and post the data to the MongoDB Server.

```
mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    intentService = new Intent();
            intentService.setClass(this, MyService.class);
            intentService.putExtra("Json Object", mJsonObject);
```

The compiler isn't allowing me to use the `mJsonObject` in the `putExtra` of the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) doesn't accept JSONObjects, so you have to convert it to another data type than can be sent through intent extras, like String:

```
intentService.putExtra("Json Object", mJsonObject.toString());
```

and then convert it back when received from `String` to `JSONObject`:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    try {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("Json Object"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Muhamed, your solution served my need...!

Answer (score 0):

You can not send the normal object using intent ,To send object from one activity to another by using intent,Object has to be serializable.

```
  So you can put data of Json Object into your custom pojo class which should implements serializable.then this pojo class object you can pass with intent
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` class does not implement `Serializable`, so you can't add it in `putExtra()` method of intent.
But you can use following two workarounds for this :

1. Use `toString()` method of `JSONObject` and add this String to intent.
2. Just extend `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` and implement `Serializable`, but please make sure that you have defined all constructors in your subclasses and implement specific methods that return the parent types such as `getJSONObject()` and `getJSONArray()`.